# Error with working cvConvexityDefect

Tags: c, opencv

I am right now working with OpenCV and Image processing. and Current topic that i am going through is, Convexity Defect. Following code that is simple program that can illustrates convexity defect, but i am getting error the error which is shown after the code. So please help me

Code :-

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int g_thresh = 128;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        CvMemStorage *hull = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        CvMemStorage *mem = NULL;
        CvMemStorage *defe_mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        CvSeq *contours = NULL;
        CvSeq *poly;
        CvSeq *convex;
        CvSeq *i;
        CvSeq *defect;
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        IplImage *gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        cvShowImage("Source", img);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvShowImage("DEstination", gray);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvThreshold(gray, gray, g_thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
        cvShowImage("BinaryImage", gray);
        cvWaitKey(0);

        int a = cvFindContours(gray, mem, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0, 0));

        cvDrawContours(gray, contours, cvScalarAll(255), cvScalarAll(255), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(0, 0));
        cvShowImage("Output",gray);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        convex = cvConvexHull2(contours, hull, CV_CLOCKWISE, 1);
        cvDrawContours(gray, convex, cvScalarAll(255), cvScalarAll(255), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(0, 0));
        cvShowImage("Convex_Hull", gray);
        cvWaitKey(0);
//Program Completely Works till here, every thing massed up after this line..   


        defect = cvConvexityDefects(contours, convex, defe_mem);

        for( i = contours; i != 0; i = i->h_next){
                cvDrawContours(gray, defect, cvScalarAll(255), cvScalarAll(255), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(0, 0));
        }

        //fprintf(stderr, "Convexity Defect::%d\n", cvCheckContourConvexity(contours));
        cvShowImage("Convexity", gray );
        cvWaitKey(0);

}
```

Error :-

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Convex hull must represented as a sequence of indices or sequence of pointers) in cvConvexityDefects, file /home/akshit/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp, line 544
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/akshit/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:544: error: (-210) Convex hull must represented as a sequence of indices or sequence of pointers in function cvConvexityDefects
```

Convex hull is found out properly with output, but convexity defect is not found out properly

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Sidenote: Try to use the new OpenCV API instead.

Comment: can i get version number, right now m using 2.4.3

Comment: 2.4.3 already support the new API.

Comment: than any solution to problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I think this code snippet should help:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h> 

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

String window_name = "Hand_HSV";
Mat frame,copyFrame;

// Detect Skin from YCrCb
Mat DetectYCrCb(Mat img,Scalar min, Scalar max)
{
    Mat skin;
    cvtColor(img, skin, cv::COLOR_RGB2YCrCb);
    inRange(skin, min, max, skin);
    Mat rect_12 = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, Size(12,12) , Point(6,6));
    erode(skin, skin, rect_12,Point(),1);
    Mat rect_6 = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, Size(6,6) , Point(3,3));
    dilate(skin,skin,rect_6,Point(),2);
    return skin;    
}

void DetectContour(Mat img)
{
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( img.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<vector<Point> > bigContours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;


    findContours(img,contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point());

    if(contours.size()>0)
    {
        vector<vector<int> >hull( contours.size() );
        vector<vector<Vec4i>> convDef(contours.size() );
        vector<vector<Point>> hull_points(contours.size());
        vector<vector<Point>> defect_points(contours.size());


        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
        {
            if(contourArea(contours[i])>5000)
            {
                convexHull( contours[i], hull[i], false );
                convexityDefects( contours[i],hull[i], convDef[i]);

                // start_index, end_index, farthest_pt_index, fixpt_depth

                for(int k=0;k<hull[i].size();k++)
                {           
                    int ind=hull[i][k];
                    hull_points[i].push_back(contours[i][ind]);
                }

                for(int k=0;k<convDef[i].size();k++)
                {           
                    if(convDef[i][k][3]>20*256)
                    {
                        int ind_0=convDef[i][k][0];
                        int ind_1=convDef[i][k][1];
                        int ind_2=convDef[i][k][2];
                        defect_points[i].push_back(contours[i][ind_2]);
                        cv::circle(drawing,contours[i][ind_0],5,Scalar(0,255,0),-1);
                        cv::circle(drawing,contours[i][ind_1],5,Scalar(0,255,0),-1);
                        cv::circle(drawing,contours[i][ind_2],5,Scalar(0,0,255),-1);
                        cv::line(drawing,contours[i][ind_2],contours[i][ind_0],Scalar(0,0,255),1);
                        cv::line(drawing,contours[i][ind_2],contours[i][ind_1],Scalar(0,0,255),1);
                    }
                }

                drawContours( drawing, contours, i, Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
                drawContours( drawing, hull_points, i, Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
            }
        }
    }
    namedWindow( "Hull demo",cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Hull demo", drawing );

}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    //VideoCapture capture("Video_Hand.MPG");
    namedWindow( window_name, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    if (capture.isOpened()){
        while(true)
        {
            //capture.read(frame);
            //flip(frame,frame,1);
            capture >> frame;
            imshow( window_name, frame);

            Mat skinYCrCb = DetectYCrCb(frame,Scalar(0, 100, 80), Scalar(255, 185, 135));
            imshow("Result",skinYCrCb);

            DetectContour(skinYCrCb);

            int c = waitKey(10);
            if( (char)c == 27 ) 
            { 
                break; 
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: plz any solution with my program ??

Comment: You'd better go to new API. But about your code: 1) cvConvexityDefects accepts as argument not points but their indices. 2) convex = cvConvexHull2(contours, hull, CV_CLOCKWISE, 1); should be convex = cvConvexHull2(contours, hull, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0); as I remember, the last parameter defines the type of return value. 3) defects is also indices, not points and not contour too, so you can't draw them as contours.

Comment: Not sure about point 3) : I found an article: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/288557/Finger-tracking-counting-using-openCv-convexity-de and there author draws defects as circles.